# How to convert a point vector layer to raster

Tags: qgis, raster, proximity

I am trying to use QGIS to calculate a proximity map around a set of points. it appears that point can't somehow be converted to raster (well they are converted but the points are not visible after being rasterized).

These points have extent from 29-33 lat, 79-89 long. And I am using WGS 72/ UTM 45N for projection.

points = vector layer

using raster->conversion -> vector to raster (doesn't seem to work, nothing inside the rasterized layer is visible)

edited:
[image: points render in vector view]
[image: raterization parameters]

Comment: As I asked previously, can you please edit your question to include the exact parameters you used in the Rasterize (vector to raster) tool. By this I mean *every* parameter, even if you left it as the default value.  Even a screenshot of the tool window will do.

Comment: It could very well be that "...the points are not visible..." because raster resolution is small, and you are not zoomed in enough to see them. Zoom in to one point, and check if a pixel appears at that point.

Comment: I've added the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raster you create has a resolution of 2 centimeter.

[image: Raster resolution]

You have to zoom extremely close to see something (e.g. scale 1:2), because one point will be shown in a pixel of 2 cm.

Raster symbology is not like vector, a raster pixel is always displayed in the raster unit which is "terrain, real unit" and not "screen unit".

To see your rasterized points at large scale, create a raster with a resolution of 2 or 20 or 200 or... meters.

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. Thanks for pointing me out. The reason it confused me was that, i was thinking the value i need to enter was height/vertical resolution. I was doing 20(m)/800 (px) = 0.02. Thanks